# Universal App Design Time Sample Data in Blend for Visual Studio 2013

Tags: data-binding, expression-blend, win-universal-app

I see that you can use Sample Data in Blend for App Store apps, but with my Universal app, it is disabled and won't let me create design time data. I've tried to search around but haven't had much luck on Universal app info with blend.

Can someone tell me if Design Time Sample Data is available for Universal apps? If not, what would you recommend doing in order to provide the designer with some fake data. Use Fixtures or Mocks?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it the same way. But if the page is on the Shared project, Blend will disable the create option (but still support it).

So,

1. Create the Sample Data files manually or
2. Create a page on Windows or Windows Phone project, then generate the Sample Data with Blend.

Now just use the d:DataContext as you are already used to do.